# How do I use the showAlert method in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to debug something and want to pop up a message dialog box. Eclipse is telling me that it wants me to "Create Method showAlert(string, string, string, boolean)"

I have imported this
    import android.content.DialogInterface;

what step am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to create and display an AlertDialog, you should user AlertDialog.Builder for example.

DialogInterface, is as its name implies, an interface and only has 2 methods: cancel() and dismiss().

Creating an AlertDialog is fairly easy:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Some Title")
.setMessage("some message")
.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // Some stuff to do when cancel got clicked
    }
})
.show();
```

That shows a simple AlertDialog.

A tip: Check Activity.showDialog(int) and Activity.onCreateDialog() they make your life easier when using dialogs.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only showing a debug message you may try [Toast.makeText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)):

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Hi there!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Don't forget to call `show()`.

Comment: Is there a way to add an acknowledge button to the Toast method?  That's why I want to use the alert dialog method.

Comment: In principle you can set the Toast layout to anything you want, but the intented use of Toast is to show little messages that go away by it's own (e.g. if you change the audio volume on your phone - that's a Toast that shows you the current volume).

Comment: Toast.LENGHT_SHORT should be Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a parameter-type mismatch. Check that your parameters are actually Strings or booleans. Maybe you need to be calling `toString()` on your objects?

Comment: Well, I've gone a different way...those are the parameters that were given from the other blog help page.  So now I am using the AlertDialog builder from developer.android.com...have gotten past that error to this: 
[2010-02-01 13:41:12 - MobileServiceCallContacts]ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.msi.ibm.tutorial/.MobileServiceCallContacts } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

and yes, I have that permission set in my manifest...where else is it supposted to go????

Comment: You should open another question for that... but as far as I know, only place permissions need to be is in AndroidManifest.xml